# How to pull individual pieces of data from a JSON to string?

Tags: java, json, parsing

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://api.wunderground.com" +"/api/106c4dee47162999/history_20060405/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"));

                    JSONObject data =  json.getJSONObject("observations.tempm");
                    System.out.println(data);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private static String readUrl(String string) throws IOException {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    String urlString = string;
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int read;
                    char[] chars = new char[1024];
                    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                        buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

                    return buffer.toString();
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

2.errors :

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["observations.tempm"] not found.
>   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
>   at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:553)
>   at com.parser.ParserObject.main(ParserObject.java:17)

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: it's import org.json.*;

Comment: Have you debugged which value is contained in `json`?

Comment: know im trying to check the root for that tempm :p

Comment: To pull out individual items you use a standard (non-Jackson-style) parser to create the corresponding "nest" of Lists and Maps and then navigate that structure.  It helps (A LOT) to be able to read and understand the JSON, so visit json.org -- it takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  And understand that a JSON "object" is equivalent to a Java Map and a JSON "array" is equivalent to a Java List.

Comment: (In the above it appears (without seeing the JSON) that "observations.tempm" is not present in the outermost JSON object.  Likely you need to "drill in" a bit to get to that value.  As I said, study the JSON and it will be clear.)

Comment: Looking at the JSON, you first extract the "history" object, then the "observations" array from that, then iterate through that array, extracting each element (which will be an "object") and extract the "tempm" String from the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersting part of the JSON you use is:

```
{'history':
  {'observations':
    [
      {'tempm':'10.0'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Use this:

```
JSONObject json = ...;
JSONObject history = (JSONObject) json.get("history");
JSONArray observations = (JSONArry) json.get("observations");
JSONObject observation0 = (JSONObject) observations.get(0);
String tempm = observation0.get("tempm");
```

If you are interested in other array elements, use a different index.

Comment: I'd like to give you +2 for such a clear presentation.

Answer (score 0):

'observations' isnt in root. you need to get 'history' first. 'observations' is a part of 'history'. and 'observations' is a list/array.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using 'jackson' or 'gson' library.parsing native json is really a pain.
you can even go to a extent of un/marshalling only required fields/objects from JSON.

Comment: He is using a parser.

Comment: Agree, he is using a parser but the final result is to fetch the information from json and get it into some object right at-least from a programming prospective.  
So why do all the work manually, i agree to the point if the organization does not allow using Jackson kind of libraries.

Comment: My observation has been that Jackson mainly allows folks to not understand JSON at a much higher level.  That doesn't seem like a good thing.